# Can Bluetooth Version be declared in Android App Manifest?

Tags: android, bluetooth, manifest, compatibility

I wanted to make use of Google's Supported Devices list (from Google Developer Console) as a device compatibility list for my App users. Google's customer support stated that the list draws from all App requirements declared in the App Manifest XML file.

In order for this list to be a good compatibility list I need to make sure it is able to take Bluetooth Versions into consideration. My App requires Bluetooth 4.0 and up, is the App Manifest able to declare for Bluetooth versions/version range? Or is it only able to declare that it uses Bluetooth in general?

Thanks!
V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't specify BT version in the manifest file. And as far as I know, you can only check, programatically, if a device has either BLUETOOTH or BLUETOOTH_LE

Answer (score 1):

In case you mean Bluetooth **LE** - you can declare

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
```

in the manifest to prevent devices that don't support it from downloading your app.

(BLE and BL4.0 are actually the same thing, but afaik some devices claim to support 4.0 but don't support the LE profile)